# Nock does not work with Nightwatch + Selenium

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js, nock

I am using nock to mock my http requests.

My app is written using Redux + React.

```
import nock from "nock"

nock("http://localhost:8080")
  .log(console.log)
  .get("/fake/users/sign_in.json")
  .reply(500, 'Error')

const doLogin = (browser) => {
  return browser
          .url("http://localhost:8080")
          .waitForElementVisible('form', 1000)
          .setValue('input[name=email]', 'foo@foo.com')
          .setValue('input[name=password]', 'somepass')
          .click('button[type=submit]')
          .pause(500)
}

export default {
  "Do login and receive success message": (browser) => {
    doLogin(browser)
      .assert.urlContains('panel')
      .end()
  }
}
```

When the request returns error 500 can not pass the test, but currently it passes. So I think that nock is not mocking the requests.

Comment: this is correct. what is the question?

Comment: I thought it was possible to make these requests

Comment: You must inject knock in the browser

Comment: How can i do this? Do you have any link?

Comment: Unfortunately no, when I have time I'll write about it (probably June)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use

```
...
.execute(`var importScript = (function (oHead) {

  function loadError (oError) {
    throw new URIError("The script " + oError.target.src + " is not accessible.");
  }

  return function (sSrc, fOnload) {
    var oScript = document.createElement("script");
    oScript.type = "text\/javascript";
    oScript.onerror = loadError;
    if (fOnload) { oScript.onload = fOnload; }
    oHead.appendChild(oScript);
    oScript.src = sSrc;
  }

    })(document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]);
     importScript('http://somewhere.com/nock.js')`)
```