# Mock backend in nightwatch.js tests

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, nightwatch.js

In my Vue.js app I'm using nightwatch to test my app. I have the following spec:

```
module.exports = {
  'wrong email or password': function (browser) {
    const devServer = browser.globals.devServerURL
    var nock = require('nock');

    var couchdb = nock('http://localhost:3000/')
                    .get('api/v1/login')
                    .reply(401, {
                      error: 'dupa'
                     });

    browser
      .url(devServer + '/login')
      .setValue('input[type=email]', 'email@example.com')
      .setValue('input[type=password]', 'password')
      .click('.login')
      .assert.containsText('#app', 'Niepoprawny email lub hasło.')
      .end()
  }
}
```

In my test I'm trying to use https://github.com/node-nock/nock. But unfortunately this not mocks any requests. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't have a good answer, but the reason Nock isn't working is that it replaced node's http functions. But Nightwatch is running in a browser-like environment, not node's so Nock has no effect.

Comment: As it was said, Nock is for testing server side code. Since here server side doesn't involve a real server and doesn't contribute to test consistency, I'd suggest to mock requests on client side instead, for example with Sinon, http://sinonjs.org/releases/v3.2.1/fake-xhr-and-server/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nock replaces the HTTP mechanism in the browser environment in which it is run.
Since you're running it in your test, which isn't running in the browser, the browser environment is unchanged.

There are several things you could do, but that depends on what you're trying to achieve:

1. You could write a fake server and have it listen at port 3000 and answer any way you like.
2. You could configure your application to use a different mechanism according to configuration, and have it load a Nock 'strategy' in the test.
3. If you have other tests checking the UI, you could replace this test with unit tests and integration tests for the functions that do the actual requests.

To write a fake, you just need a simple server that returns the answer you want. Here's an example with express.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/api/v1/login', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Some response')
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('server listening on port 3000')
})
```

Comment: Any examples for nightwatch? I'm unable to find good examples how mock api backend in nightwatch...

Comment: Nightwatch doesn't provide this functionality. It is basically a WebDriver implementation (Selenium). To run a fake backend, you need to write one. If you do it with node and [express.js](https://expressjs.com/) it can be done in a few lines of code.